# Adding values from a list of queries with a specific "step"

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was wondering if there is a way to add values to an array, within a range `[x, y]` (having a list of queries) with a specific "step", faster than `O(queries * (range_length / step))`: you should add values like this: for each `pos = x + k * step`, where `k` goes from 0 to infinity, `pos <= y`, `array[pos] += value`.

I thought about adding the value in another array, like this:

```
auxarray[x] += value;
auxarray[y + 1] -= value;
for (int i = 1; i <= size; ++i) {
    auxarray[i] += auxarray[i - 1];
    array[i] += auxarray[i];
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know what to do with the cells that the value shouldn't be added to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the question right, but if I did why not doing:

```
curr = x;
while (curr <= y) {
    array[curr] += value;
    curr += step;
}
```

Regarding the `faster than O(queries * range_length)`, I don't think it is possible, though it is acctually:
O(queries * (range_length **/ step**))

Comment: That was my approach as well, but as I can see, it takes a high amount of time. The number of queries can go to 100000, so can the length of the array.
Edit: Indeed, it's `length / step`, but I am wondering if I can use another arrays or data structures.